# How do gzip don't find two same part?

Tags: compression, zlib

I wrote such code

```
#include "zlib.h"
unsigned char dst[1<<26];
unsigned char src[1<<24];
int main() {
    unsigned long dstlen = 1<<26;
    srand (12345);
    for (int i=0; i<1<<23; i++) src[i] = src[i | 1<<23] = rand();
    compress(dst,&dstlen,src,1<<24);
    printf ("%d/%d = %f\n", dstlen, 1<<24, dstlen / double(1<<24));
}
```

which tries to compress two same 2<sup>23</sup> bytes part connected together. However, the result is

```
16782342/16777216 = 1.000306
```

How is data with such rule not compressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum distance for matching strings in zlib is 32,768 bytes back.

Comment: I tried and the maximum N for `for (int i=0; i<N; i++) src[i] = src[i + N] = rand();` is 32506